# How to transform the dataframe

Tags: r, excel

Faced trouble using R trying to transform my dataset.
The dataset is larger, with more food types, person IDs and "how often" options.

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

This type of transformation is called a "pivot". We are "pivoting" the data set from a long (many rows) format to a wide (many columns) format. This is easily done using the `tidyr` [pivot_wider](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html).

```
library(tidyr)
df_transformed<-df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from="food_type", values_from="how_often")
```

Comment: Hi @Joe, thank you for your advice! I'm new to R, and after "pivoting" the dataset, I get a list of c(1, 3, 2) for person 1 under French food column. I was wondering how to create multiple rows instead of creating 1 row for each person containing all their "how often" points.

Comment: I understand the pivot_wider() creates list columns when there are any duplicated values, was wondering how to preserve the duplicated values

Comment: this is a little closer but still not exactly your output df_transformed<-df %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  relocate(id, .before=person) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="food_type", values_from="how_often")